# Differences in the Select by expression between QGIS 2.18 and 3.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-2, select-by-attribute

I want to select in a population table the growth rate between two years greather than 1.5.

In QGIS 2.18 the following expression works fine

```
"POP_P2014" / "POP_P2000" > 1.5
```

With the same data table and with the same expression, it doesn't work in QGIS 3.4.

How should i build expression in QGIS 3.4?

In QGIS 2.18
[image]
In QGIS 3.4, don't work
[image]

Comment: Drop the spaces, drop the parenthesis' ("), then try again.

Comment: Could you write an example?

Comment: `Column1/Column2>1.5`

Comment: IMHO your expression should work. Can you be so kind show a print screen of your attribute table? For instance, when I am selecting something with `"Attribute" > 0.5` it works as usual.

Comment: I tried in Qgis 3.4.15 and 3.10.3 and both expression are working properly. It must be one error on your data

Comment: Check if both table are numeric type.

Comment: Emilio, if both columns are integer datatypes in a shapefile, division doesn't seem to work properly in QGIS 3.10+. See this question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356528/problem-with-select-by-expression-in-qgis/356529 I've lodged an error report. Try using `eval()` or a different file type in the meantime.

Comment: GREAT!!! @she_weeds, eval() works fine in 3.4 and 3.10, now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It should work in QGIS 3.4 as well. Your expression syntax is not OK. You should write the name of fields enclosed in inverted commas aka quotation marks (""). See the difference in your QGIS 2.18 expression and 3.14. Or simply try this expression `"INE_P2014" / "INE_P2000" > 1.5`.

[image: Difference in Expression]

Comment: "INE_P2014" / "INE_P2000" > 1.5  it doesn't work. It was my first choice. I've tried without "" as suggested by @Erik, but it doesn't work for me either

Comment: Then problem may be something else, corrupted data or installation. Have you tried some different data or on another computer?

Comment: maybe a configuration difference between your two qgis installs, something related with the **decimal separator** ? _(since your screenshot doesn't seem to mean 'syntax error' but rather 'no feature selected' ...)_

Comment: exact, does not give syntax error, but does not make the same selection as in version 2.18, when the data is the same

Comment: Are you opening the project file made in QGIS 2.18? Or you opening a new project and added this shapefile? Maybe try this. Besides are some other shapefiles working fine especially working of field calculator and use of field names in the expression?

Comment: I open a new project, and add the data. Don't work. When I use other data, also doesn't work. The solution that works is to use the field calculator and store the result of the division, and then select on its result. But that's not what I'm looking for, that's what works in 2.18

Comment: Besides, is there any special reason to work with 3.4? My experience with QGIS3.4 was also not good as it used to crash to often in the middle of doing many tasks. The problem resolved when I updated the installation to 3.6 (latest at that time).  Maybe if possible, upgrade to QGIS 3.10.3 the current LTR or to the latest QGIS 3.12

Comment: I need to use 3.4, but I try in 3.10, and it doesn't work. Same problem that in 3.4. Thanks by the interest.